# Raspbian "Segmentation fault" after running for months

Tags: linux, raspbian

I have Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

```
Linux version 4.1.18-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) )
```

There is Apache, PHP and MySQL running. It reads data from another LAN device, logs it to MySQL DB and sends it to remote server. Rows in MySQL table are deleted 7 days after they are written, but only if they are successfully sent to server.

On boot a service starts file `loop_send.sh` which calls PHP script every 10 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
WAITTIME=10
while [ $COUNTER -lt 5 ]; do
    /usr/bin/php /var/www/send.php
    sleep $WAITTIME
    #let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

send.php checks if there are new records in MySQL and sends them to the remote server.

There is similar service, .sh and PHP file for reading data from LAN and writing to MySQL table.

This worked fine since June 2016. At August 31st it stopped reporting to the remote server but remained powered on and connected to the network until now.

In `/var/log/sendservice.err` there are thousands of:

```
loop_send.sh: line 9:  3702 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/php /var/www/send.php
loop_send.sh: line 9:  3708 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/php /var/www/send.php
loop_send.sh: line 9:  3711 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/php /var/www/send.php
loop_send.sh: line 9:  3716 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/php /var/www/send.php
loop_send.sh: line 9:  3722 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/php /var/www/send.php
loop_send.sh: line 9:  3725 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/php /var/www/send.php
loop_send.sh: line 9:  3728 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/php /var/www/send.php
loop_send.sh: line 9:  3735 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/php /var/www/send.php
```

Followed by a lot of:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/curl.so: symbol steerr, version GLIBC_2.4 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/communication.php on line 71
```

and then:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=aPI2013q226,NTS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,NTS
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/communication.php on line 71
```

and then:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/curl.so: symbol steerr, version GLIBC_2.4 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/communication.php on line 71
    invalid subsection length 4194340, max allowed 36
```

This log file is 45MB, every one of these messages repeats a lot before the next one.

I guess the "Segmentation fault" is the reason for everything else, but I cant find the reason for it. There was no monitor and input devices on the Pi before this happened.

Comment: Did you check, if the shared library for php-curl is existing? Looks like its not and php doesn't provide any curl functions anymore, because it's missing. And when this changed, it's likely you did something, what changed it. Have a look what update/intalls/uninstalls you did (dpkg.log may help) or try to install everything needed again and see what was missing.

Comment: The file `/usr/lib/php5/20131226/curl.so` is there and it's readable. I am 100% sure I did nothing, last dpkg log is from March 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear from your output that the data being loaded into memory doesn't match what *should* be coming off your media. For instance:

> ID=aPI2013q226,NTS

This is showing multiple single-bit errors. The other log entries you posted also suggest that the programs being loaded are similarly corrupted.

Check that your SD card or other media isn't failing.